# Bind Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

How would I go about binding this in XAML?

I am looking to use an observable collection to populate a `ListView` ever time a method is called which will be through a drop event on another control. The collection is getting added too but the `ListView` won't populate.

I haven't been using WPF long so any insight would be great.

```
namespaceA 
{
    public class SomeClassA
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClassB
    {
        public void MethodA()
        {
            ObservableCollection<SomeClassA> Name_Col = new ObservableCollection<SomeClassA>();
            Name_col.Add(new SomeClassA { FirstName = "SomeValue" });
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ObjectDataProvider
    x:Key="Viewmodel"
    ObjectType="{x:Type Local:NamespaceA}"/>

 <ListView DataContext="{StaticResource Viewmodel}"
    Height="396" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="766,67,0,0" 
    Name="listView1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="260" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Name_col}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only things you can access in bindings are `public` (`internal` doesn't work) properties and indexers of `public` classes.

And no matter how, variables declared *inside a method* will never be accessible from anywhere outside the said method. It's a common mistake people who used to work with scripting languages often make. To access something outside a method (or inside of another), that must be declared outside of the method.

One useful hint: Visual Studio's `Output` window is a very useful tool for tracking binding errors.

On a side note: Bindings are case sensitive. Even if your code followed the rules mentioned above, WPF would still not find the binding source, as your binding path is `Name_col`, but the property's name is `Name_Col`.

Comment: Makes sense that it can't be set as static; not enough coffee in me today I suppose.  The case was a typo as it wasn't a copy and paste.  I will just have to implement my custom interface for the drop event in the code behind I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code

First off, your DataContext is pointing to a namespace, not an object. Change that to be an instance of an object.

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Viewmodel" ObjectType="{x:Type local:SomeClassB}"/>
```

Or

```
<local:SomeClassB x:Key="Viewmodel" />
```

Second, your `ObservableCollection` is not a public property, so your View cannot see nor access it.

```
public class SomeClassB
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeClassA> Name_Col { get; set; }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        Name_Col = new ObservableCollection<SomeClassA>();
        Name_col.Add(new SomeClassA { FirstName = "SomeValue" });
    }
}
```

And last of all, WPF bindings are case-sensitive so you need to fix the `ItemsSource` binding to use the correct case

```
<ListView ... 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Name_Col}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is pasted, your binding is looking at a nonexistent property.  Try capitalizing the 'c' in your binding.  Name_col -> Name_Col

Comment: That still won't work as the desired binding source is declared inside a method.

Comment: Also your you need to declare Name_Col as a public property on SomeClassB